# How to recognize a left to right swipe motion?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uigesturerecognizer

If I am trying to recognize a swipe motion of of left then right or left to right. Would I need to use a `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` with a `UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft` direction then dynamically add another `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` with a `UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight` direction?

Then when the user lifts their fingers I remove the gesture recognizer with `UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight` direction?

Answer (score 2):

If I'm understanding you correctly and you just want to detect a left to right gesture you only have to use `UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight`. Here's an example:

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeLeftToRight = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(myMethod:)];
[swipeLeftToRight setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight];
[swipeLeftToRight setDelegate:self];
[someView addGestureRecognizer:swipeLeftToRight];
```

Comment: No, I am looking for someone to swipe right and then left so  [finger down, swipe right, swipe left] and [finger down, swipe right, swipe left, finger up].